# Bad Hostname provided - NotFoundHttpException thrown in

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

I got this error NotFoundHttpException raised with a message say "Bad hostname provided" even though it run locally when trying to save data from Flutter using Dio package but when used Postman, it worked fine no error raised. Have been workaround but no solution to this problem. Any idea why this error occurred?

Code:

```
public function store(StoreSaleRequest $request)
    {
$waybillNumber = GenerateUniqueId::create('sales', 'FMC', $request->customer_type === 'regular' ? 'R' : 'D', 7, true);
            
            $customer = $this->createOrUpdateCustomer($request);
    
            $sale = Sale::create([
                'customer_id' => $customer->id,
                'waybill_number' => $waybillNumber,
                'amount_paid' => $request->amount_paid,
                'cod' => $request->cod,
                'date' => $request->date ?? now(),
                'total_price' => $request->total_price,
                'delivery_fee' => $request->delivery_fee,
                'subtotal' => $request->subtotal,
                'transaction_id' => $request->transaction_id,
                'customer_type' => $request->customer_type,
                'discount' => $request->discount,
                'payment_type' => $request->payment_type,
            ]);
    
            $sale->salesItems()->createMany($request->items);
    
            $this->updateStock($customer->id, $request->items);
    
            if ($sale->customer) {
                SmsJob::dispatch(
                    config('services.default_sms'),
                    $sale->customer->phone,
                    "message",
                )
                    ->delay(now()->addSeconds(20));
            }
    
            $sale->load('salesItems');
    
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Sale saved successfully',
            ]);
        }
```

Error:

```
message: Bad hostname provided., exception: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException, file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php, line: 414, trace: [{file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php, line: 384, function: prepareException, class: Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php, line: 51, function: render, class: Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php, line: 185, function: handleException, class: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php, line: 39, function: Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}, class: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php, line: 180, function: handle, class: Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php, line: 116, function: Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}, class: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php, line: 175, function: then, class: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php, line: 144, function: sendRequestThroughRouter, class: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/public/index.php, line: 51, function: handle, class: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel, type: ->}, {file: /Users/okmans/Projects/FM Cosmetics/app/erp project/sports/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php, line: 16, function: require_once}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a method - POST explicitly like this:

"_method": "POST" before sending. I don't know how it worked.